# get url parameter in cakephp

Tags: url, cakephp

Kinda having a problem here since I am not getting the search results in google correctly. What I want to do is to simply extract this confirmation code in this url:

```
http://localhost/myproject/webactivate/activate/4fe114bf590c410597b20ef8ac1000751340150975vU0t70lN
```

I would like to get this

```
4fe114bf590c410597b20ef8ac1000751340150975vU0t70lN
```

It must be something simple..

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague, but assuming you have an `activate` method in your controller, you can access the activation code in the following way:

```
public function activate($activationCode) {
    // do something with $activationCode
}
```